# How do I run a block of code in IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I run a block of code in IntelliJ IDE without running the entire script?

E.g: My block of code is

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .master("local") 
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

// job to do something_1

// job to do something_2

// job to do word count

val inputFilename = "/path/to/file"
val data = spark.read.text(inputFilename).as[String]

val words = data.flatMap(value => value.split("\\s+"))
val groupWords = words.groupByKey(_.toLowerCase)
val counts = groupWords.count()
counts.show()
```

Here, I want to execute all the lines below `//job to do word count` and NOT the blocks for `// job to do something_1` or `// job to do something_2`.

This is similar to executing a cell in Databricks or Qubole. I wish to know if IntelliJ has a similar feature?

It would be great for debugging that way I can verify the values of each variable without running the entire script.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this in a Scala worksheet.

1. In the project pane on the left, right click a surce directory and select **New => Scala Worksheet**
2. paste your code into the worksheet, adding imports as necessary
3. run the worksheet